# Impossible connect from Tableau srv to PostgreSQL srv

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

We have Tableau srv deployed on Ubuntu srv on Virtual Machine.

Version
Tableau Services Manager command line version 20211.0.0.0.
Tableau Server version 20211.21.0511.0935.

We make extract on Tableau from PostgreSQL12 - unsuccessfully, meanwhile test connect - success.
And can connect to PostgreSQL10's DBs.

Use PostgreSQL connector to connect. And when we update Extract, we catch the error:

This job failed on Aug 16, 2021, 5:26 PM after running for 0.2 min because of: java.lang.RuntimeException: Errors occurred while trying to load the workbook "tempDailyportalordersbyplatform". The load was not able to complete successfully. Protocol 1 is unavailable Unable to connect to the PostgreSQL server "X.X.X.X". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.

Maybe somebody faced with such issue?

Comment: "*Protocol 1 is unavailable*" sounds as if you are using an outdated Postgres client library or driver.

Comment: You need to install an updated jdbc driver on your Tableau Server.  Please follow this wizard:  https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers